# how do you extract data from data frame columns that contain certain text

Tags: regex, r, dplyr

I have this data frame:

dput(df)

```
structure(list(Time = structure(1:4, .Label = c("1/29/2015 2:00", 
"1/29/2015 2:10", "1/29/2015 2:20", "1/29/2015 2:30"), class = "factor"), 
    WTAD..SNMP..AppTier.BIGIP.SNMP.CPU.5min.avg.on.Web01.Content.Match = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "n/a", class = "factor"), WTAD..SNMP..AppTier.BIGIP.SNMP.CPU.5min.avg.on.Web01.Status = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "n/a", class = "factor"), WTAD..SNMP..AppTier.BIGIP.SNMP.CPU.5min.avg.on.Web01.Value = c(12L, 
    12L, 12L, 12L), WTAD..SNMP..AppTier.BIGIP.SNMP.Memory.on.Web01.Content.Match = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "n/a", class = "factor")), .Names = c("Time", 
"WTAD..SNMP..AppTier.BIGIP.SNMP.CPU.5min.avg.on.Web01.Content.Match", 
"WTAD..SNMP..AppTier.BIGIP.SNMP.CPU.5min.avg.on.Web01.Status", 
"WTAD..SNMP..AppTier.BIGIP.SNMP.CPU.5min.avg.on.Web01.Value", 
"WTAD..SNMP..AppTier.BIGIP.SNMP.Memory.on.Web01.Content.Match"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

I am trying to column that contains this: CPU.5min.avg.on.*.Value"

```
library(dplyr)
df<-select(df, Time, contains("CPU.5min.avg.on.*.Value"))
```

This work on windows R but not linux. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @MaratTalipov that was my mistake. The data frame is df, I corrected it on the post.

Comment: @MaratTalipov, this works on windows R but I need this working in Linux, not seem to be working. I only get the Time column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base R solution:

```
df[,c("Time",colnames(df)[sapply(colnames(df), function(u) grepl("CPU.5min.avg.on.*.Value",u))])]
```

Comment: I also need Time column.

Comment: Thank you it worked. I am little puzzeled that dplyr did not work under linux.

Answer (score 2):

`dplyr` solution:

```
select(df, Time, matches('CPU.5min.avg.on.*.Value'))
```

Actually, I am puzzled that your solution worked under Windows. `?select` documentation says:

> contains(x, ignore.case = TRUE): selects all variables whose name
>   contains x
>
> matches(x, ignore.case = TRUE): selects all variables whose name
>   matches the regular expression x

and you're trying to match the regular expression in your code, so it shouldn't work with `contain` under any OS.